# how to handle salt in password in dotnetcore web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, hash

I am implementing password hashing in my .net core web application by implementing IPasswordHasher of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity


public class PasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher<AppUser>
{
    private byte[] salt { get; set; } = new byte[16]
    {
        85,236,4,227,4,141,4,37,4,4,5,7,21,143,49,136
    };

    public PasswordHasher()
    {
        //salt = CreateSalt();
    }

    private byte[] CreateSalt()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16];
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }

    public string HashPassword(AppUser user, string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
        }
        else
        {
            var argon2 = new Argon2id(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

            argon2.Salt = salt;
            argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = 8; // four cores
            argon2.Iterations = 4;
            argon2.MemorySize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 GB

            var bytes = argon2.GetBytes(16);

            string bitString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);

            return bitString;
        }

    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(AppUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashedPassword) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(providedPassword))
        {
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
        }

        string comparePassword = HashPassword(user, providedPassword);

        var isValid = hashedPassword == comparePassword;


        return isValid ? PasswordVerificationResult.Success : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }

}
```

I have below questions,

1. Is it right to hardcode salt ? If not the salt used while storing the hash in database can be different from salt whilewe try to login?
2. If the existing application in production uses some old encryption should we manually decrypt all users passwords and hash their passwords if we need to release?

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode security related parameters.
Please read [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0) to learn about default implementation of `IPasswordHasher`.
In the default implementation Microsoft derives a salt randomly and it will concatenate this salt with hashed password (Password already being hashed with that salt)

In verification it will separate this 16byte salt and does validation against hashed password again with the same salt.

When you want to override default `IPasswordHasher` you should override both `HashPassword` and `VerifyHashedPassword` and as long as it's being used in `UserManager` it will be applied both in setting passwords and login operation.

and about your second question, password hashes are one-way encryption most of the times. If you are able to decrypt them so do it. but if you not, you can offer change password to your end-users. still you need to accept the old password with the old implementation. When all of them has changed their password you can remove backward compatibility for the old implementation and replacing your own.